# How To Host Multiple Vite Apps in One Django Project?

Tags: django, vite

### Problem

How would I host multiple vite applications built on different architectures (vanilla and react) in the same Dango instance?

I have a a django app that had a pre-es6 javascript front end that I converted to a vite vanilla javascript application, delivered using the [wonderful Django-Vite plugin](https://github.com/MrBin99/django-vite). The app is working fine, but now there's a request to add a new react-based vite app to the existing django project, and django-vite does not support hosting multiple vite applications out of the box.

### Thoughts

1. Have a single vite app that would redirect to another vite app, one of the two I need to build (not sure how this would work)
2. Merge both vite `manifest.json` files together at build time to be served from a single location (don't know what the ramifications would be)
3. ~Host a NextJS app external to Django~ (insert unicorns and rainbows here) <-- Can't do this one because leadership thinks integration would be more effort than it's worth

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that MrBin99, maintainer of the plugin, [created a branch to do this](https://github.com/MrBin99/django-vite/tree/multi-config). It was a little out of date from the `main` branch, so I tweaked it a bit. [Here's the code I wrote](https://gist.github.com/Jgordon-pencilwrench/67cd3bc4d504c6ad4ca81ff76ae11fa3).

**NOTE**: *I really only modified the functions my app needed, specifically for React, so you may need to alter other functions depending on your needs. Functions I use:*

1. `vite_react_refresh`
2. `vite_asset`
3. `vite_hmr_client`

This breaks the way the app's configured. You'll need to configure it in you settings.py like so:

```
DJANGO_VITE = {
    "compose": {
        "assets_path": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "path", "to your", "js"),
        "static_url_prefix": "js/directory",
        "dev_mode": DEBUG,
    },
    "complaints": {
        "assets_path": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "path", "to your", "js"),
        "static_url_prefix": "js/directory2",
        "dev_mode": DEBUG,
        "dev_server_port": 3001,
    },
}
```

Given it modifies the configuration so much, it would be a break from what's in `main`. We have this working fine in production.